# Numbers default to open TSV/CSV files as Windows Latin 1. How can I change that to unicode?

Tags: numbers, encoding, unicode, csv

Desktop-Numbers on Ventura defaults to open TSV/CSV files as Windows Latin 1/1252. How can I change that to unicode?

I tried adding a magic number in the beginning of the file (I am building the file myself) but Numbers seemed to ignore that (or I failed to do it properly).